# How can I get vehicle's count in veins 5.0?

Tags: veins

In veins 4.7.1 I can have getVehicleCount() in TraciScenarioManger class.
But In veins 5.0 this method is not available instead of a protective variable activeVehicleCount.
I defined 
'''
TraCIScenarioManager* Tracscene'
'''
but when I use 
'''
Tracscene->activeVehicleCount
'''
I got an error
"uint32_t veins::TraCIScenarioManager::activeVehicleCount’ is protected within this context"

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Creat a sub class to visit it.

```
class VEINS_API myTCM : TraCIScenarioManager {
   public:
     int getVehicleCount(){
          return activeVehicleCount;
         }

};
```